# UITableViewCell selectedBackgroundView staying pressed after pushing and popping a VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

NOTE: Please read THOROUGHLY before marking my question as a duplicate. The steps to repeat the issue state that I am pressing and holding on to the table view cell, which means that I never "select" the cell (for further proof `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` never gets called)

I have an issue within my UITableView where my UITableViewCell would at times maintain its selected state after pushing and popping a VC.

The steps to i've found to repeat this issue would be:

Press and hold on a table cell
click the accessory button on a table cell to push a view
Clicking the back button to return to the original table view
result: the table cell that was pressed on is still in it's selected state.

This is the only code that I have in my UITableViewCell subclass relative to its selection state:

```
self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

since didSelectRowAtIndexPath does not get called in this case, i cannot use indexPathForSelectedRow to revert the button's state

is there anything i'm possibly doing wrong inside or outside of this code?

Answer (score 1):

The `selected` state of a cell gets set on touch down, not on touch up.  To verify this, note that the cell background color changes when you touch a cell, not when you release the touch.

Should still be appropriate for you to call `deselectCell...`

Comment: so then why would didSelectRowAtIndexPath not get called when attempting my STR?

Comment: Because `didSelect...` gets called on touch up.  With many controls there is a distinction between the appearance during a touch, and the action associated with the touch.  Buttons show highlighted while you're touching them, but don't act until you release, etc.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that the `selected` state of the cell is merely applying a visual affect.  The actual selection is indicated by `didSelect...`

Comment: I've tried `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];` on `viewDidAppear`/`viewWillAppear`, and both did not work for me, is there anything else i can do?

Comment: Call `setSelected` on the cell directly.  The problem is basically that you're interrupting the normal flow of things by touching the cell twice :)  I'd recommend doing it in the accessory action if you're using one, or the prepareForSegue if you're using a segue directly from the accessory.

Comment: hey @David.. so i believe this to actually be an iOS7 bug... if you go to the Phone app on your iPhone device-> go to Favorites -> and try the STR on this SO question, youll get the same result